# ABAP VA02 user exit to block end user from deleting line item's from sales orders

Tags: abap

I have modified user exit "MV45AFZB" FORM "userexit_check_xvbap_for_delet" to keep users from deleting line items from sales orders in t-code VA02.  However if they double click the line item and go into the schedule lines.  They are allowed to delete the line item.  What FORM or additional user exit do I need to code for in able to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USEREXIT_CHECK_XVBEP_FOR_DELET  is the form to add the additional code too.  It will prevent users from deleting line items from a scheduled line.

http://scn.sap.com/thread/756922

Answer (score 0):

You could put some code in USEREXIT_SAVE_DOCUMENT_PREPARE to stop the user from saving if they've deleted line items.

Comment: Do you know the user exit that should be called if they delete from the scheduled line section?